# How remove dynamic fields with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, field

I am learning javascript with dynamic fields and I wanted to be able to eliminate them besides making them match with the table,to later use css
I just need to use javascript

javascript code:

```
function create(){
    var div = document.getElementById("fields");
    var array=document.getElementsByName('txt[]');
    var length = array.length+1;

    var jump = document.createElement("P");

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("name", "txt[]");
    input.setAttribute("id", "txtCamp" + length);
    input.setAttribute("size", "20");
    input.className = "input";

    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.setAttribute("name", "txt2[]");
    input2.setAttribute("id", "txtCamp2" + length);
    input2.setAttribute("size", "20");
    input2.className = "input";

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "txtCampo3"+ length);
    button.innerHTML = 'Add field';
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "create()");

    var button2 = document.createElement('button');
    button2.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button2.setAttribute("id", "txtCampo3"+ length);
    button2.innerHTML = 'delete field';

    jump.appendChild(input);
    jump.appendChild(input2);
    jump.appendChild(button);
    jump.appendChild(button2);
    div.appendChild(jump);
}
```

And the table in html

```
<table width="50%"  border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="7">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="button" id="boton" value="Create field" onclick="create();" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Item1</th>
    <th>Item2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>      <td>
      <div id="fields"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean you want to remove attributes from the created nodes? Or that you want to remove elements altogether?

Comment: yes sir 
i need to remove  from the created nodes

Comment: Then [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) is probably what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! and how it would be remove elements altogether?

Comment: For that you need [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a function by first getting that particular element and then you can remove it for example

```
function removeElt(elementId) {
   var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```